# Simple console menu

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I'm a beginner in node and I'm trying to build a simple console menu. I kept searching for this but coulnd't find a proper answer.

When I run the script I want to display a menu and ask the user to enter an option. After he chooses, I perform an action then display the menu again.

I tried using a while loop but it's blocking my program.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
int userRes = -1;

while(userRes != 0){
   console.log("Option 1")
   console.log("Option 2")
   console.log("Option 3")
   userRes = readLineSync.question("Pick an option");
   if(userRes == 1){
      doSomething();
   }else if (userRes == 2){
      doSomethingElse();
   }
}
```

EDIT: Actual code bellow. As you can see I use stomp. The while loop displays my menu and the action inside the if statement gets executed.
The problem is, when stomp sends back the response my code in the subscribe function is not being executed.
I tried without a while (just the action) and it works perfectly.

```
var Stomp = require("stomp-client");
const readlineSync = require("readline-sync");
var client = new Stomp(host, 61613);
function conn(res,req){
  client.connect(function(sessionId) {
    client.subscribe("/queue/" + res, function(body, headers) {
      console.log(body);
    });
    var res = -1;
    while (res != 0) {
      displayMenu();
      var res = readlineSync.question("Introduceti o optiune: ");
      if (res == 1) {
        client.publish("/queue/" + req, "test");
      } else if (res == 0) {
        process.exit();
      }
    }
  });
}
function displayMenu() {
  console.log(
    "Option one\n Option two\n 0 for exit";
  );
}
```

Comment: Please, post the actual code. That one doesn't run. At least require()s are missing and there is no "int" in javascript.

Comment: I posted the actual code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code

```
const readLineSync = require('readline-sync')

let userRes;
while (userRes !== '0') {
    console.log("Option 1")
    console.log("Option 2")
    console.log("Option 3")
    userRes = readLineSync.question("Pick an option");
    if (userRes === '1') {
        doSomething()
    } else if (userRes === '2') {
        doSomethingElse()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example implementation without additional libraries. As a bonus, after selecting the menu item, it is possible to enter additional information:

```
import * as readline from 'readline';

export class Menu {
    private currentIndex = 0;
    constructor(private menuItems: string[]) {}

    private colorText(text: string, color: string): string {
        const colorCodes: Record<string, string> = { reset: '\x1b[0m', green: '\x1b[32m', blue: '\x1b[34m' };
        return `${colorCodes[color] || colorCodes.reset}${text}${colorCodes.reset}`;
    }

    private renderMenu(): void {
        console.clear();
        console.log(this.colorText(`1. PLEASE, SELECT ITEM: `, 'blue'));
        this.menuItems.forEach((item, i) =>
            console.log(i === this.currentIndex ? this.colorText(`→ ${item}`, 'green') : `  ${item}`),
        );
    }

    private async inputText(prompt: string): Promise<string> {
        const rl = readline.createInterface({
            input: process.stdin,
            output: process.stdout,
        });

        return new Promise(res => {
            rl.question(prompt, (answer: string) => {
                rl.close();
                res(answer);
            });
        });
    }

    async run(): Promise<{ selectedItem: string; text: string }> {
        return new Promise(async res => {
            const handleKeyPress = async (str: string, key: readline.Key) => {
                if (key.name === 'up') {
                    this.currentIndex = this.currentIndex > 0 ? this.currentIndex - 1 : this.menuItems.length - 1;
                } else if (key.name === 'down') {
                    this.currentIndex = this.currentIndex < this.menuItems.length - 1 ? this.currentIndex + 1 : 0;
                } else if (key.name === 'return') {
                    process.stdin.setRawMode(false);
                    process.stdin.removeListener('keypress', handleKeyPress);
                    const text = await this.inputText(
                        this.colorText(`2. PLEASE, ENTER ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: `, 'blue'),
                    );
                    return res({ selectedItem: this.menuItems[this.currentIndex], text });
                } else if (key.name === 'c' && key.ctrl) process.exit(0);

                this.renderMenu();
            };

            readline.emitKeypressEvents(process.stdin);
            process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
            process.stdin.on('keypress', handleKeyPress);
            this.renderMenu();
        });
    }
}

new Menu(['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3']).run().then(res => console.log(res));
```